What proof does a company need when it claims a customer has damaged a piece of their equipment
I rented a car from a car rental company for 2 weeks and they are claiming that I caused a dent in the bumper of the car.  Looking online this company seems to have a reputation for making such claims where the user has no recollection of causing any damage.
I don't believe that I caused any dent, although it is possible.  As proof they provided a photo of the car with a the dent showing and the number plate also visible.  But no photo of the bumper prior to us taking out the rental.
Do they have to provide a before photo?
Is the onus on the client to photograph the car prior to the booking.  [Which would be difficult to record every little detail].
The company are charging 300 euros for the damage.  The dent is not really a dent, just a mark.
I am interested in how a legal court would see this?  The car was rented in Slovenia, I am British.
